# count(*)=0 не выводит строки с 0, не join запрос

Tags: sql

В таблицу не попадают строки с quest_rk, у которых количество равно 0...

Запрос:

```
Select
quest_rk, count(*) as cnt
From
my_analytics.game
where (quest_rk = 31 or quest_rk = 7 or quest_rk = 9 or quest_rk = 19) 
and (game_dttm > '2022-11-30 23:59:59.999' and game_dttm < '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000')
group by quest_rk 
order by quest_rk
```

Подскажите, плиз, как быть...

Comment: Ну так вы не выбираете записи с `quest_rk = 0`

Comment: Задача  - посчитать для заданных quest_rk количество игр при определенных условиях, и мне нужно, чтобы count(*)=0 тоже выводилось в итоговой табличке! Например  так:
quest_rk    cnt
(7,                0)
(9,                2)
(19,              5)
(31,              0). 
А я получаю вместо четырех строк всего две.

Comment: Ну так уберите из where `(quest_rk = 31 or quest_rk = 7 or quest_rk = 9 or quest_rk = 19)`

Comment: Мне не надо quest_rk = 0! В таблице вообще нет quest_rk = 0, т.к. они нумеруются с 1-го. Вопрос про count(*) - можно ли как-то его настроить, чтобы в выводе были строки , где count(*) насчитал 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добиться результата удалось, создав отдельным запросом дополнительную таблицу из нужных мне quest_rk и объединив её с выборкой подходящих под критерии игр (game) через left join. Тогда в итоговой таблице проставляются нули, и все quest_rk из дополнительной таблицы есть.

```
Select
t1.quest_rk, count(t2.quest_rk) as cnt
From 
(
select quest_rk
from my_analytics.quest
where quest_rk in (7,9,19,31)
) t1
left join my_analytics.game t2 
    on t1.quest_rk=t2.quest_rk
and (game_dttm > '2022-11-30 23:59:59.999' 
     and game_dttm < '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000')
and (game_flg = 1)
group by t1.quest_rk 
order by t1.quest_rk
```

Comment: Ну в общем-то правильное по сути решение, да.

Answer (score 1):

Не проверял:

```
Select
t2.quest_rk, count(t1.quest_rk) as cnt
From (
my_analytics.game
where (quest_rk = 31 or quest_rk = 7 or quest_rk = 9 or quest_rk = 19) 
and (game_dttm > '2022-11-30 23:59:59.999' and game_dttm < '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000')
) t1  right join my_analytics.game t2 on t1.quest_rk=t2.quest_rk
group by t2.quest_rk 
order by t2.quest_rk
```

Comment: Прям в лоб не получилось использовать, т.к. тут подзапрос не полный, и ещё пришлось покрутиться и со второй таблицей и с join. Но идея понятна - что делаем доп.таблицу с нужными quest_rk и потом через join объединяем со строками, найденными по условиям. Спасибо!! Чуть ниже оставлен работающий ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить вот такой вариант, если я правильно понял, что хочется получить:

```
select a.quest_rk, count(g.quest_rk) from
(
  select 1 quest_rk from dual
  union
  select 2 from dual
  union
  select 3 from dual
  union
  select 4 from dual
  union
  select 6 from dual
) a
left join game g on a.quest_rk=g.quest_rk
group by a.quest_rk
```

Создаем выборку из нужных значений, далее при помощи **left join** цепляем нужную таблицу и считаем `count(quest_rk)` (не `count(*)` - т.к. со * считаются строки, а при указании столбца считаются значения, отличные от **null**)

Comment: Посмотреть можно на [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hVcvACAD4xcbtPRzR9TxmF/0)

Comment: не ясно про dual - что за сущность?

Comment: @Jane_Brown Системная таблица, созданная для вызова функций вне реальной таблицы. По простому, все что указано в select вернется как строка из таблицы. В примере выше вы получите таблицу с числами

Comment: Если скопировать ваше решение в лоб (конечно заменив game на правильное название), то DBeaver ругается "dual not exist"

Comment: По итогу ответ получился как у вас, с left join. Но левая таблица по-другому получена. dual у меня не работает, даже не подсвечивается как спец.слово. БД Greenplum.